# Xamarin Forms IOS - Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Seems today, I'm not able to publish my IPA to Itunes Connect.

I receive this :

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register
>   with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's
>   entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your
>   app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is
>   enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit
>   after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not
>   automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning
>   profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this
>   entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's
>   Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your
>   entitlements file. For more information, see
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

The thing is that I'm not using Notification Push in my app....

I check my certificats, and all are active.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is the release configuration have the linker enabled for at least "Framework SDK" and/or are you using a 3rd library that is using notifications?

Comment: I will have a look. But my last try yesterday works ( I don't know why it's work ).